# Find the analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

$f(z)=1 $ satisfies the condition
Using Identity Theorem $f(z)=1$ can be only function that satisfies this.
so option (b) is NOT true.
Am I on correct path?

Comment: How is the condition $f(z) = f(z^2)$ to be understood, since $z \in D$ does not imply $z^2 \in D$ ?

Comment: Assume $f$ is defined on entire plane and analytic on $D$

Comment: I don't understand your use of the Identity Theorem, could you please elaborate on it please?

Comment: I realized that I am wrong in approaching this problem. I thought if  $f(z)=1$ satisfies $f(z) = f(z^2)$, $f(1)=1$ and is analytic on $D$. Any other function satisfying $f(z) = f(z^2)$ must be constant function 1. Any Hint ?

Comment: Using the fact that $f(z)$ is analytic, hence continuous, and the functional equation $f(z) = f(z^2)$, you can deduce $1-\epsilon < f(x) < 1+ \epsilon$ for $0<x<2$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Thus...?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the question it's enough to prove that the hypotheses on $f$ force it to be identically $1$ on $D$ to solve the problem.

By contradiction assume that $f(z) \not \equiv 1$ in $D$, then, by the identity theorem applied to the real interval $(0,2) \subset D$, there exists $x_0\in(0,2)$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 1$. Without loss of generality let us assume $f(x_0)>1$; then we choose $\epsilon$ such that $1< 1+ \epsilon < f(x_0)$.

By continuity of $f$, and $f(1)=1$, there exists $\delta$ such that $f(x) < 1+\epsilon$ for any $x \in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$. Using the functional equation $f(x) = f(x^2)$ whenever $x\in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$ we deduce $f(x) < 1+\epsilon$ for any $x \in (1-2\delta +\delta^2, 1+2\delta+\delta^2)$. Iterating this argument we conclude $f(x) < 1+\epsilon$ for any $x \in (0,2)$.

Contradiction with $f(x_0) > 1+\epsilon$.